# How to parse empty columns getting displaced within TSV?

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a TSV file that I want to parse. There are empty fields in all columns resulting in displacement of the order of columns, so that not all the values I get using a certain column number actually come from that column.

Some fields contain long strings with empty space inside them. Also, some columns contain potential delimiters like `;` `|` `:`

Input file

```
 columnA    columnB    columnC    columnD
 A1         B1         C1         D1
 B2         C2         D2    
 A3         D3
 A4         B4         D4
```

Desired output

```
 columnA    columnB    columnC    columnD
 A1         B1         C1         D1
            B2         C2         D2    
 A3                               D3
 A4         B4                    D4
```

`$file myfile`

```
`ASCII English text, with very long lines`
```

`$awk '-F\t' '{print NF}' myfile | sort | uniq -c | tail -n`

```
`247871 136`
```

I have found this code posted in reply to a similar question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/how-to-display-tsv-csv-in-console-when-empty-cells-are-missed-by-column-t), but I cannot make this work for my file:

```
sed ':x s/\(^\|\t\)\t/\1 \t/; t x' < file.tsv | column -t -s $'\t'
```

(The problem persists after importing into Excel.)

Comment: What happens if you load it into Excel?

Comment: The columns would still get displaced. Also, the number of columns are ~200, and number of rows are 250K.

Comment: So your values are `A1, B2, C3` etc or are they just examples?

Comment: @jaypal, These are examples. The actual fields are long in some columns, containing all sort of potential delimiters like `;` `|` `-` etc

Comment: why do you call it a TSV if you don't have extra tabs for empty columns. You need to go back to your source to fix this. How will you ever know if, just for starters, your first column is missing, and every field is at least off-by-one? (Or am I misunderstanding your question). Best post sample data with '#' chars or something visible for column separators to help clarify your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, The extension of this file is tsv.txt. So, I am not sure how to categorize it. When I do e.g. `awk '{print $8}'`, not all lines have the values they should for that specific column. This problem exists in Excel too. I did not understand how I could post the sample data here? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend a combination of `expand` to convert tabs to spaces and then using `awk` with fixed field sizes - something like `expand < input.tsv.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="8 8 8 8 ..."}{ .... }'`. You'd have to manually strip trailing spaces within `awk` using `gsub` or something, though... Although, in your example, I'm not sure how you're supposed to be able to tell that D3 belongs in the fourth column, not the second or third...

Comment: @twalberg, The problem is that in my actual data, some columns contain long strings with spaces inside. So, if I convert tab to space, I would have problem with those columns?

Comment: Consider for instance row number 2 of the input file: how du you know that B2 belongs to column B? Is the first character always a B? If not, it seems difficult to know which of the 4 columns actually contains the empty field.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, Based on the header row, I expect certain type of values. For example `$2` should contain name of genes, but when I do `awk {print $2}` not all lines contain corresponding values. A similar question is asked in this link, and may help clarify mine. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/how-to-display-tsv-csv-in-console-when-empty-cells-are-missed-by-column-t

Comment: consider editing your post with the output of this cmd, using your real file. `awk '-F\t' '{print NF}' bigFile | sort | uniq -c | tail -5`. If you have a well formed tab-delimited file, you should only get 1 line of output. If you get more than 1 line, then you can see if the counts have any regularity to them. (Don't be afraid to change the `tail -5` to `tail -50` or other number). Is it possible that this is really an even bigger line broken into multiple lines? Finally, if source of file is Windows and you working in Linux, don't forget to `dos2unix bigFile`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, Thanks! I got the same count for all `tail -n` (247871 136). I did `dos2unix` as well.

Comment: so this proves that NO records have missing fields. There may not be any data in a field, so then I would expect to find N number tab-chars ajoining each other where there is missing data, but using `awk '-F\t' -v OFS="\t" '{print $9, $12, $15, $18}' file`  (for example) should give you consistent results. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, Thank you very much! It works nicely! What is the difference between `'-F\t'` and `-F\t` ? Please post your solution, so I could chose it as the answer.

Comment: briefly, quoting the '\t' ensures that it is passed to awk as a complete string (and not evaluated by the shell (before it gets to awk)). I'll post better answer tonight. Busy now. Glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
FieldEmpty='   '
FieldSize=${#FieldEmpty}

sed "
s/A/&/
t B
s/^ */ ${FieldEmpty}/
t B

: B
s/B/&/
t C
s/^ .\{${FieldSize}\}/&${FieldEmpty}/
t C

: C
s/C/&/
t D
s/^ \(.\{${FieldSize}\}\)\{2\}/&${FieldEmpty}/
t D

: D
s/D/&/
t
s/^ \(.\{${FieldSize}\}\)\{3\}/&${FieldEmpty}/
" YourFile
```

If more column are used, an iterative way is to be used instead (same concept of test/"insert")

On my AIX/KSH (so should be the same as with `--posix -e` on GNU sed)

```
$ cat YourFile
 columnA    columnB    columnC    columnD
 A1         B1         C1         D1
 B2         C2         D2
 A3         D3
 A4         B4         D4
$ FieldEmpty='           ';FieldSize=${#FieldEmpty};echo $FieldSize
11
$sed "..." YourFile
 columnA    columnB    columnC    columnD
 A1         B1         C1         D1
            B2         C2         D2
 A3                               D3
 A4         B4                    D4
```

Comment: I am very new to sed, so sorry if my questions are very basic. First, I cannot get your code to work for the sample file. I am on ubuntu. I tried it both in the form you wrote and `sed --posix -e "..." YourFile`. Given your definition of `FieldEmpty`, I think I would have problems with my actual data, as some columns contain spaces within the cells content. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a error message or just the data not output like wanted ?

Comment: In bash, I get this (with or without `--posix -e`): `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'`

Comment: try may be putting the content between `"` in a file and use `-f ` followed by the file name in place of `-e " ..."`

Answer (score 0):

If your file is tab separated, you should use tab as a field separator in `awk`. Like

```
$ column -t -s $'\t' file

columnA  columnB  columnC  columnD
A1 1     B1 2     C1 3     D1 4
B2 2     C2 4     D2 4
A3 1     D3 4
A4 1     B4 2     D4 4

$xxd file
0000000: 636f 6c75 6d6e 4109 636f 6c75 6d6e 4209  columnA.columnB.
0000010: 636f 6c75 6d6e 4309 636f 6c75 6d6e 440a  columnC.columnD.
0000020: 4131 2031 0942 3120 3209 4331 2033 0944  A1 1.B1 2.C1 3.D
0000030: 3120 340a 0942 3220 3209 4332 2034 0944  1 4..B2 2.C2 4.D
0000040: 3220 340a 4133 2031 0909 0944 3320 340a  2 4.A3 1...D3 4.
0000050: 4134 2031 0942 3420 3209 0944 3420 340a  A4 1.B4 2..D4 4.

$ awk -F'\t' '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%-8s ", $i
    }
    print ""
}'

columnA columnB columnC columnD 
A1 1    B1 2    C1 3    D1 4    
        B2 2    C2 4    D2 4    
A3 1                    D3 4    
A4 1    B4 2            D4 4
```

Comment: Could you explain how `xxd file` should be run? Should I save the output and run the `awk` code on it? In your answer, are the individual numbers in the fields for demonstration? Thank you!

Comment: @user2162153 Yes the numbers are just for demonstration, so you can see that they have spaces inside. Replace `file` with your file (`myfile`).

Comment: @user2162153 `xxd` is just for demonstration. It shows that the input file contains tabs as separators. The hexadecimal code for a tab is `09`.

Comment: Thank you. It did not work on my data. As I am not sure if I made the example file in the same format as of the real one, I cannot say that it did not work for it. The solution that was just provided in the comments below the post (the third from the bottom) resolved the issue. I appreciate your help.